# Is there an easy and succinct way to say this? (question regarding the relative pronoun: who/whom)

Tags: grammar, sentence, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, who

Say I wanted to shorten the phrase "It's on the back of the man who is over there" so that the first clause becomes "the man's back."

Is there any way to move from there with any kind of conjunction? I want to continue describing the man though, not his back.

> It's on the man's back who is over there.
>
> It's on the mans's back whom is over there.
>
> It's on the man's back, his who is over there.

How can I do this? If it's possible at all...

Comment: I think you need to edit the question, it's a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the back of the man"? What was on the man's back? It makes no sense.

Comment: **It's on the man's back, over there.** If it's on the man's back anyway, they're both "over there"; so that should be sufficient.

Comment: You could say "It's on the man over there's back":  this is grammatical but a bit clunky.

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, you could say, "It's on the man's back over there," but this is dependent on your audience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've made "It" in "It's on the man's back" the subject. If you want to make the man the subject again, you can use a kind of colloquial appositive/interjection. In the second example below, that will result in a sentence fragment. Depending on your writing style and audience, that might not be a problem:

e.g.
"It's on the man's back--the man who is over there."
or 
"It's on the man's back. The man who is over there. He's a real pal." etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a solution within the structure you're using, but you might try restructuring it.

One option is "**See that man over there? It's on his back.**" Depending on the context, you could also use the narrative as well as the actual statement: "**'See him?' Paul pointed at a tall man walking down the busy street. 'It's on his back.'**"